# What's the relationship between `struct file` and file descriptor?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

I know that a `struct file` is a kernel representation for an opened file and a file descriptor is for user space to use. But I still have some questions:

- Is `struct file` and fd many-to-one? Can multiple file descriptors in the same process share one `struct file`?
- If the answer is yes, can multiple file descriptors in **different** processes share the same `struct file`?
- If the answer is yes, how does the kernel keep track of the fd-specific information such as the current file offset?

Comment: `struct file` actually corresponds to opened file, so sharing `struct file` from multiple file descriptors is the same as **sharing opened file**. And that phrase can be easily googled. Calling `dup` allows a single process to have two file descriptors pointed to the single opened file. After `fork`, corresponding parent and child file descriptors point to the same opened file. "how does the kernel keep track of the fd-specific information such as the current file offset?" - Current file offset is a part of the opened file, so it is shared too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So normally, let's say I open a file 2 times in a single thread, then I get 2 file descriptors, these 2 file descriptors actually don't share the same file struct in kernel space, right?

Comment: Yes, different `open` calls create different `struct file` objects.

Comment: If you look at the `open(2)` man page description of an *open file description*, that is pretty much what is being represented by the kernel's `struct file` object when the `open` syscall returns a file descriptor.